# Find Equation of Angle Bisector Given Points

Tags: geometry

> The points $(0,9), (12,0)$ and $(0,0)$ create a right triangle. Find the equation of the angle bisectors for each of the three angles on the triangle.

I am unsure of how to find the equations. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible approach is to find the location of the incenter through
$$ I = \frac{aA+bB+cC}{a+b+c} =(3,3)$$
then the equations of the lines $AI,BI,CI$ are pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach for the bisector at $(0, 9)$.

The angle $\theta$ at $(0, 9)$ has $\cos\theta = \frac{9}{15} = \frac{3}{5}$, so the tangent of the half-angle is $$\tan{\frac{\theta}{2}} = \sqrt{\frac{1-\cos\theta}{1+\cos\theta}} = \frac{1}{2}\,.$$
This means that the bisector from $(0, 9)$ intersects the $x$-axis at $(\frac{9}{2}, 0)$. So just find the equation of the line containing $(0, 9)$ and $(\frac{9}{2}, 0)$.